# Puppet Bolt not Passing Parameters into Bash Script Running as Task

Tags: bash, shell-script, puppet

When trying to use Puppet Bolt to run Bash scripts on remote machines, I kept having scripts fail to work properly because they weren't receiving the parameters passed by the Bolt command. If a ran a script as a task like such:

`bolt task run --targets localhost madeUpModule::scriptTakeInUserAndGroup user='testuser' group='testgroup'`

`No user or group defined` as per the condition I defined for the script.

This is all after testing the script locally and knowing it can handle parameters.

Why isn't the script/task receiving the parameters?

---

Comment: Thank you for sharing what you've learned! However, while that is very welcome here, we need everything to be in the form of a question or an answer. So please [edit] your post and make it a question, and then post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Please consider adding your answer as a proper answer. It's totally fine to answer one's own questions, but please do so in a proper answer. Additionally, when you started writing your question you should have seen a "Answer your own question" checkbox, which, if checked, would have given you an answer box to put your self-answer into. Now, just cut and paste your answer from the question into an answer box below.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This had been posted as part of the original question, so I (terdon) am posting it as a CW answer instead**.

---

Okay, so I found the solution to this question already before posting. I just wanted to make a post since I wasted time on this even though its documented:

> [If the script isn't installed, or you want to make it into a cohesive task so that you can manage its version with code management tools, add code to your script to check for the environment variables, prefixed with PT_, and read them instead of arguments.](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/writing_tasks.html#adding-parameters-to-metadata)

I am trying to run a script on a remote machine, initially thinking I could pass parameters into the bask script through stdin as $1, $2, etc. Those variables receive the values entered after the launching of the script in Bash like: *./scriptTakeInUserAndGroup user group* (In which echo $1 would print *user* since its the first param passed).

This didnt work in puppet bolt. Puppet bolt has two options for input_method when it comes to unix: [stdin and environment](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/writing_tasks.html#adding-parameters-to-metadata). I have had no luck using the stdin option as of yet, but I found that the environment variable works once you find out it messes with the name of your variables:

`bolt task run --targets localhost madeUpModule::scriptTakeInUserAndGroup user='testuser' group='testgroup'`

Does not pass these variables by the name you call them in the JSON metadata.

If you put `printenv | grep user` in the script you will see the following in your environment: `PT_user=testuser`.

It is, rather annoyingly, adding `PT_` ahead of your variable name. So the bash script you have running with $user is breaking

If you modify your script to use `$PT_user` it will work just fine.